# Performance Testing With Gatling for an SSO Login UI Application

Tags: scala, performance, single-sign-on, load-testing, gatling

I have been doing Performance testing using Gatling Tool for an UI Dashboard with SSO , With single user I am able to capture Response time . With Multiple Load the Test fails with Connection Time Out error as There is no load applied on SSO Authentication .
This Dashboard can have 100+ Users load , So I am planning to have around 5 test users that will not have SSO Logins, so that the load can be simulated for testing . Is there are way we can use SSO Authentication of an UI for Gatling?